# Programmatically Adding a "Binding Name" to a PCF Service in Java Spring App

Tags: java, spring, cloud-foundry

I am deploying a Java Spring app to PCF and need it to automatically bind to a few user-provided services. However, for a few reasons, I need to provide a "binding name" to the service so that the app references the binding name, not the actual name of the service. Is there a way in the manifest.yml file to programmatically assign a binding name when the app is deployed?

** Here is the abbreviated manifest.yml file -- I'd like to bind the app to use "credential service-v1", but with a binding name of "credential-service".

```
services:
  - credential-service-v1
```

I tried looking [here](https://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/services/application-binding.html#named-service-bindings) but couldn't find exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing this, I do not believe that's possible with just `manifest.yml`. The support of service binding is pretty weak in `manifest.yml`. Again, at the time of writing this it's just a list of service instance names that you want to bind to.

https://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest-attributes.html#services-block

If you want to do more complicated things like have a service binding name or say pass service specific configuration parameters, you have to use the cf cli or the API directly.

My suggestion would be to cobble together a short shell or Powershell script that drives your deployment. You'll probably want to `cf push --no-start` to get things going, then you can `cf bind-service` and any run any other app configuration commands, then finish up with `cf start` to stage and run the app.